# realloc crashes when pointer has an offset

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, realloc

I have below a simplified C program that demonstrates the problem. When I try to call `realloc` using a pointer, it works fine, but if I try to add an offset to the pointer(i.e. to start from a later element in an array), it fails.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

struct arbNum{
    unsigned char* bytes;
    long len;
};

void trim(struct arbNum* num){
    printf("%d,%d,%d,%d\n",num->bytes,num->bytes[0],num->bytes[1],num->len);
    unsigned char* nbytes = realloc(num->bytes,num->len);
    printf("Realloc successful.\n");
    num->bytes = nbytes;
}

int main(void){
    struct arbNum p = {calloc(2,1),2};
    trim(&p);
}
```

As an example, this outputs:

```
9247152,0,0,2
Realloc successful.
```

But, from the above code, changing `realloc(num->bytes,num->len);` to `realloc(num->bytes+1,num->len-1);` changes the output/behavior to this:

```
10361264,0,0,2
```

And then crashes. It may be that I do not understand pointers at all, but my current understanding is that they are essentially addresses at which another value is stored. In this case, why would supplying the `pointer+1` not point to the value stored in the address one higher than the pointer, or in other words, what would act as the 1st element of an array pointed to by that pointer. What I'm trying to do is copy an array pointed to by `num.bytes` starting at the 1st element to a new address in memory, but clearly, it's failing for some reason.

Answer (score 9):

No, you can only `realloc()` on the actual pointer previously returned by `malloc()` or family.

Otherwise, it's [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.22.3.5

> If `ptr` is a null pointer, the `realloc` function behaves like the `malloc` function for the
>   specified size. Otherwise, if `ptr` does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory
>   management function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to the `free` or
>   `realloc` function, the behavior is undefined. [....]

So, you're not *allowed* to use pointer aritmatic go generate a new address, pass that to `realloc()` and expect to re-allocate partially, that makes no sense.

Comment: Right. And apparently I can use `memcpy` to do what I wanted.

Comment: @user2649681 well, even before that, you'll hit UB.

Comment: @user2649681 "apparently I can use `memcpy` to do what I wanted"  --> doubtful.  But `memmove()` may work.